# How to import framework sources into an IDE

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I would like to contribute to PlayFramework 2.0.

Building from the command line is really not the best way to work on this overcomplex language called Scala. It really needs an IDE to ease comprehension. ( btw see http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/scala-sink-or-swim-part-2/ for more details on this topic)

What is the preferred IDE to work on the framework sources, and how to import the code ?

In other words, how do play developers work ? What is their setup ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is not all that difficult:

#### get the source

```
git clone https://github.com/playframework/Play20.git
```

#### add IDEA plugin

*to `framework/project/plugins.sbt`*:

```
resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.0.0")
```

#### generate IDE friendliness

```
[...Play20/framework]$ sbt gen-idea
```

Comment: hum, isn't play built on sbt ? where is your sbt command coming from ?

Answer (score 4):

Today Idea, Eclipse and Ensime - all supports importing sbt project. So, it's up to you which one to choose.

Looking through commits on [Play20/.gitignore](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commits/master/.gitignore),
[Ignore IntelliJ IDEA projects](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/c13d666d919d23e23e90aff9a89a8e5e70ac1b31) commit tells that some of developers are using Idea,
[Finalized integration with sbteclipse, using sbteclipse 2.0.0-M3.](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/49163e48957f5670545da15bd859c9e7ad2a7243) commit tells there is Eclipse support out of the box.

I'd add that I am using Ensime with Play for a long time. It just works as well as with other sbt projects.

#### Ensime support

*plugins.sbt*:

```
resolvers += ScalaToolsSnapshots
addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt-cmd" % "latest.milestone")
```

from sbt console

```
$ ensime generate
```

Comment: +1 thank you, approved the other one b/c I prefer IntelliJ but your answer is just as pertinent.